# DNS for Azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-dns

I have a service bus old.servicebus.windows.net where my clients are connected. I am creating a new service bus with different configurations called new.servicebus.windows.net. What are the options where I can give my clients' a common name and then have the requests forwarded? Is it possible? So that, in future, even if i change my service bus, they can still be forwarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the options where I can give my clients' a common name and
> then have the requests forwarded?

AFAIK, it is not possible to do so. You should try to migrate your clients from old Service Bus Namespace to the new Service Bus Namespace.